# What does it mean when a company says they are "Entrepreneurial" in a job ad?

Tags: job-search, recruitment, company-culture, job-description

I am looking for a new job, and a recruiter forwarded me an opening with a company.

The job description describes the firm as very "entrepreneurial". They aren't a large company, but they do have about 100 people and have been around for 10 years.

I have an interview with the hiring manager on Friday, and I do plan on asking him. However I am worried that this "entrepreneurial" is corporate jargon for either "messy", "chaotic", and/or "short-staffed".

What could I do to know what this could mean?

Comment: Yes, messy, chaotic, short-staffed, cultish, unpaid overtime, ego-driven, no training, but it could also be positive, opportunities for growth, less red tape, employee stock, and doing cool stuff.

Comment: You could google search the name of the company. There are many websites that show the current or former employees' feedback about the company work culture, the management style, salary, interviews, etc...

Comment: Also, it could mean that you are expected to work 80 hours per week with no extra pay on projects that get killed just after you finish them.

Comment: "Entrepreneurial" generally means the employer is conducting an insurgency against another, and you are at the sharp end of an attack on the target's workforce. Exactly what form the attack will take cannot be guessed, but it will be something worse than at a non-entrepreneurial firm. The possibility that the insurgency is taking place using better methods and organisation, or more investment, and not an outright undermining of pay and conditions, is a vanishingly small possibility in my experience.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### It doesn't mean anything.

Statements like this are the equivalent of "world Class,"  "customer-centric," and "disruptive."  It is a marketing phrase that only has the meaning that the person making it means.  Maybe it means that everyone acts like and are treated like owners, but maybe it means they want you to think they act like a sole proprietorship when really you're drawing a salary and will be treated like an employee.

Comment: or maybe it's just a buzzword someone likes

Answer (score 8):

I'm afraid that only this manager has the answer to this. We can only guess. Perhaps they are in the startup industry and that's what they mean? But again, this is a wild guess. **Ask them**. Good thing you have an upcoming interview.

In the meantime, you could consider researching or learning about what that company does in the internet, so you can get an idea of what this could be before you ask them.

Alternatively, consider asking your recruiter (the one who sent this as you are telling us), if they have any information on the nature of this company and what could "Entrepeneurial" mean.